# Can't figure out "if else" code correctly?

Tags: matlab

```
if APC<-2.9079
     BUYz='z'
     SELLy='y'
elseif APC>0.44
     BUYy='y'
     SELLz='z'
else
end
```

x and y are both single column matrices.

I want the system to check if the APC column is above or below the values as mentioned above, if yes, pick up corresponding values from x and y.

Do you think I have entered this correctly?
When I try the code it does not create BUYy or any of the others.

Thanks for all the help.

Clarification:

I have loaded an excel file in Matlab using xlsread. It has columns such as x, y, APC, Date etc.

I am using the "if else" statement in the command window after loading the file.

Comment: `x` and `y` are not in your code. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Edited. Not sure if I need to include them in this if else statement? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a brief introduction to `if` and `elseif` for vectors.

Suppose `A = [1 2 3]`, then the following will not result in `B = 5`.

```
if A > 2
   B = 5;
end
```

The reason for this is because what the `if` sees is `(A > 2) == [0 0 1]`. The first `0` will cause the statement to be false, thus it will skip the rest.

Similarly, the following will also not result in `B = 5`.

```
if A < 2
   B = 5;
end
```

The reason for this is because the `if` now sees `(A < 2) == [1 0 0]`. The `if` requires all of the elements to be true for it to "jump into it". The two below are equivalent:

```
if A < x
```

and

```
if all(A < x)
```

`elseif` behaves the exact same way.

Suppose `y = [1 2 3]`, doing `x = 'y'` will not give you `x = [1 2 3]` but `x = y` (the character "y", not the variable. If you want the `x` variable to be equal to the `y` variable you simply do `x = y`.

So, what can you do?

If I understand you correctly, you have a vectors similar to this (might be decimals, but that doesn't matter).

```
APC = [1, -3, 4, -2, 0];
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
y = [6 7 8 9 10];
```

You want `BUYx = x(2)`, and `SELLy = y(2)` since the second element is the only one in APC that's less than `-2.9079`.

You also want `BUYy = [y(1), y(3)]` and `SELLx = [x(1), x(3)]`, since the first and third element of APC is larger than `0.44`.

What you can do is:

```
BUYx = x(APC < -2.9079)
SELLy = y(APC < -2.9079)
BUYy = y(APC > 0.44)
SELLx = x(APC > 0.44)
```

This returns:

```
BUYx =
     2
SELLy =
     7
BUYy =
     6     8
SELLx =
     1     3
```

If you only want the first elements and not all of them, you can use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/find.html) like this:

```
BUYx = x(find(APC < -2.9079,1,'first'))  
SELLy = y(find(APC < -2.9079,1,'first'))
BUYy = y(find(APC > 0.44,1,'first'))
SELLx = x(find(APC > 0.44,1,'first'))
```

`find(x < y, 5, 'first')` find the first 5 elements where `x < y`. `find(APC < -2.9079, 1, 'first')` finds only the first element where `APC < -2.9079`.

**or** just do as the first approach and then: `BUYx = BUYx(1)` to only get the first elements.

It might be I have misinterpreted your question, but I think this will get you well on your way nevertheless. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I have a question though, now it is basically taking a lot of values and storing them to the Variable(BUYx etc). I am wondering if its possible to make it stop at the first value it recieves and then use that value to calculate Profit loss after initiation of position till termination. Will have to define a rule for that. ? Thanks. Just need a lot of help and working through a problem set should get me programming faster. :)

Comment: Thanks. It works. Now onto the next problem. :) Can't decide whether I should continue here or ask a new question.

Comment: Valuable explanations +1